# Excel - Evaluate multiple cells in a row and create report or display showing lowest to highest

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel 2003 spreadsheet, I have the top row of cells calculating the number of days and hours I have worked on something based on data I put in the cells below for each category. For example I enter the time spent on Programming, Spoken languages, house, piano, guitar...etc. The top cell in each category will keep track of and display how many days and hours I spent as I add the time spent for each category each day. I want to evaluate this top row and then list in a "report" (like a pop up box or another tab or something) in order from least amount of time to the most amount of time. This is so I can see at a glance which category is falling behind and what I need to work on. Can this be done in Excel? VBA? Or do I have to write a program from scratch in C# or Java? Thanks!

VH

Unbelievable... I've been scolded for trying to understand an answer and requested to mark this question answered. I don't see anything to do this and could not find anything that tells you how, so I'm just writing it here. MY QUESTION WAS ANSWERED... But thanks anyway...

Comment: I can definitely be done in Excel using VBA and potentially without using VBA.   If you already have it in Excel, you should look into the built in sort function.  You can also look at built in formulas like SMALL.

Comment: Do you have some example data?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: know how your data is layed out or what you have done so far can help people answer your question and help you develop e a solution.

Comment: @ForwardEd, please keep the chatter down. Edit your comments instead of adding new thoughts as they come to mind. Or move it to chats.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The chart data is built with formulas in columns H3:I3 and below. The formulas are

H3 `=INDEX($B$3:$F$3,MATCH(SMALL($B$2:$F$2,ROW(A1)),$B$2:$F$2,0))`

I3 `=INDEX($B$2:$F$2,MATCH(SMALL($B$2:$F$2,ROW(A1)),$B$2:$F$2,0))`

Copy down and build a horizontal bar chart from the data. If you want to change the order of the source data, use `LARGE()` instead of `SMALL()`.

**Alternative Approach**

Instead of recording your data in a matrix, consider recording in a flat table with columns for date, category and time spent. That data can then easily be evaluated in many possible ways without using any formulas at all. The screenshot below shows a pivot table and chart where the data is sorted by time spent.

[image]

**Edit after inspecting file:**

[image]

Swap rows 2 and 3. Then you can choose one of the approaches outlined above.

Consider entering the study time as time values. It is not immediately clear if your entry `2.23` means 2 hrs and 23 minutes, or 2 hrs plus 0.23 of an hour, which totals to 2hrs, 13 minutes.

If you are using the first method, then all your sums involving decimals are off. For example, the total for column B is `7.73` as you sum it. Is that meant to be 7 hrs and 73 minutes? That would really be 8 hrs and 13 minutes, no? Or is it meant to be 7 hrs and 43 minutes? You can see how this is confusing. Use the colon to separate hrs and minutes and - hey - you can see human readable time values and don't have to convert minute values into decimals.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn... What you have in the first shot is what I want. I already have the spreadsheet laid out with each row for a day. I will try to copy a screen shot but it's not on this computer so I put it in a Word document.

Comment: I'm a programmer but wanted to do something in Excel for a change of pace..:) One problem is that the headers tallying the days and time are formatted to display text so I'm confused as to how I would get this into those formulas. I also don't know how to create a graph like you did.

Comment: This chopped half of my first comment for some reason.... It is not intuitively obvious how to paste a screen shot from the Word document in here so I guess I can't do it. Each column header tallys the days and hours and displays it as "4D, 3.45H" for 4 days, 3.45 hours.

Comment: Why don't you create a sample Excel file with dummy data. Make sure it has the same data structure and formats as your real file. Make sure it uses the same formula to tally the totals. Then upload it to one of the many free file sharing services and post the url of the file link. A file is even better than the picture that is better than 1000 words. Post a comment here when you've done that, so I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn! I put a file called TimeTrackingSample and Teylyn message in 4Shared at https://www.4shared.com/account/home.jsp#dir=0COSfP4W   I hope this is the correct link and it should be shared. Thank you!  If that link does not work then try: https://www.4shared.com/office/sAiJsu0Lba/TimeTrackingSample.html

Comment: Would you mind using something like Dropbox, Google Drive or OneDrive? I am getting hammered with ads, but cannot download the file.

Comment: Ok Teylyn....here is the link for the shared files/folder in OneDrive: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FD4E0C2086275AA3!124&authkey=!AEJaehjrQ_tpcPw&ithint=folder%2crtf

Comment: Thank you teylyn! I will give this a try. The decimal is just the total minutes I spent divided by 60. I actually enter the total minutes and hit "/ 60". So 2.23 is 2.23 hours, or 134 minutes = 2 hours and 14 minutes. This is a little crazy as it is just for me and making this on the fly, it just got done this way in a hurry...:)

Comment: I tried a simple test using your formula scheme but it is not working. I looked up the syntax of the match and index functions and understand them basically, but I don't understand how you used your formulas. Did you put the same formula in each line of where you show your results? If so what do you change in each one? Or do you select the block of cells used for the results and past the one formula into it? Or something different.The index function is placing the found value in the designated cell right?. The match function is finding the smallest value. But how do you get the ranked results?

Comment: "not working" is not good enough. Which approach did you select? The formula solution uses the SMALL() function to rank. The pivot table uses sorting on the values to rank. If that is "not working" for you, then you are not applying it correctly. This is not a chatty forum. Your question has been answered, as shown in the screenshots, and you should mark the answer. If you still don't know how to achieve what you want, pick one of the two posted techniques and work with it. Post a new question with your approach so far and explain what's not working.